# How to check Flat List if item is zero in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using Flat List to render my items  but i am having an issue when the items are coming from server the flat list is working fine but when there is no item in the response from server the list is generating error how can i handle empty list here is my code.

```
fetchFreelancerData = async () => {
    const Pid = await AsyncStorage.getItem("projectUid");
    console.log(Pid);
    const response = await fetch(
      BaseUrl + "listing/get_freelancers?listing_type=favorite&user_id=" + Pid
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    //       {json[0].type != "error" ?
    this.setState({ fetchFreelancer: json });
    //       }
  };
```

Here is my function where i am fetching the data , and here is Flat List where i am rendering the data

```
<FlatList
                style={{ paddingBottom: 5, paddingTop: 10 }}
                data={this.state.fetchFreelancer}
                keyExtractor={(y, z) => z.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => 
                  (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={0.9}
                    onPress={() =>
                      this.props.navigation.navigate("DetailFreelancerScreen", {
                        profile_id: item.profile_id,
                        user_id: item.user_id
                      })
                    }>
                    <FreelancerCategory
                      imageUrifreelancer={{ uri: `${item.profile_img}` }}
                      imageUrifeatured={{ uri: `${item.badge.badget_url}` }}
                      featuredColor={`${entities.decode(item.badge.badget_color)}`}
                      flagimageUri={{ uri: `${item.location.flag}` }}
                      freelancername={`${entities.decode(item.name)}`}
                      title={`${entities.decode(item._tag_line)}`}
                      rate={`${entities.decode(item._perhour_rate)}`}
                      country={`${entities.decode(item.location._country)}`}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )
                }
              />
```

please suggest me a good way to handle empty list

Comment: Whats the response of the server when there is no data ? empty array or a different object ?

Comment: check the value of json if it not what you need then set fetchFreelancer to empty array

Comment: [
  {
    "type": "error",
    "message": "You have no employers in your favorite list."
  }
]
@GuruparanGiritharan

Comment: @CuongTranDuc i need to show an image if array is empty

Comment: @CuongTranDuc can you show me a sample code please

Comment: so you need to show a default image in flatlist if no data returns from server ?

Comment: @CuongTranDuc yeah i want to show an image if list is empty

Answer (score 4):

add **ListEmptyComponent** prop to flatList and render what you want!

```
<FlatList
  style={{ paddingBottom: 5, paddingTop: 10 }}
  data={this.state.fetchFreelancer}
  ListEmptyComponent={this.renderNoStateMessage()}
/>
```

**render Method.**

```
renderNoStateMessage = () => {
  <View>
    <Text>You have no employers in your favorite list.</Text>
  </View>
}
```

Comment: Where i need to set KeyExtractor and render item?

Comment: this also prop - keyExtractor={this.listItemKeyExtractor}

Comment: listItemKeyExtractor(item, index) {
        return (item && item._id) ? item._id : index+'';
    }

Comment: You helped someone(me) after 5 years you posted the answer. Thanks dude!!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use try/catch.

```
try {
    const response = await fetch(
      BaseUrl + "listing/get_freelancers?listing_type=favorite&user_id=" + Pid
    );
    const json = response.json();
    this.setState({ fetchFreelancer: json });
} catch (e) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should set the state for the data only if you have valid data, something like below

```
fetchFreelancerData = async () => {
    const Pid = await AsyncStorage.getItem("projectUid");
    console.log(Pid);
    const response = await fetch(
        BaseUrl + "listing/get_freelancers?listing_type=favorite&user_id=" + Pid
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    if (json.type !== "error") {
        this.setState({ fetchFreelancer: json });
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: json.message,fetchFreelancer:[] });
    }
}
```

Then you have to use the ListEmptyComponent in your FlatList

```
<FlatList
    style={{ paddingBottom: 5, paddingTop: 10 }}
    data={this.state.fetchFreelancer}
    keyExtractor={(y, z) => z.toString()}
    ListEmptyComponent={<Text>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>}
    renderItem={({ item }) =>
        (
            <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={0.9}
                onPress={() =>
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("DetailFreelancerScreen", {
                        profile_id: item.profile_id,
                        user_id: item.user_id
                    })
                }>
                <FreelancerCategory
                    imageUrifreelancer={{ uri: `${item.profile_img}` }}
                    imageUrifeatured={{ uri: `${item.badge.badget_url}` }}
                    featuredColor={`${entities.decode(item.badge.badget_color)}`}
                    flagimageUri={{ uri: `${item.location.flag}` }}
                    freelancername={`${entities.decode(item.name)}`}
                    title={`${entities.decode(item._tag_line)}`}
                    rate={`${entities.decode(item._perhour_rate)}`}
                    country={`${entities.decode(item.location._country)}`}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
/>
```

Comment: after ListEmptyComponent ... renderItem will not work if data is empty???

Comment: Edited the answer you can simply set an empty array so the flatlist would render the empty element